# UFW not working in 16.04 server. Refers to earlier kernel module?

Tags: server, kernel, iptables, 16.04, ufw

I am trying to move our mail server based on 12.04 to a brand new installation of 16.04 server.
When I run `sudo ufw status`, I get:

```
ERROR: problem running iptables: modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-85-generic/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/3.13.0-85-generic
iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

This seems odd as 16.04 uses the 4.4 kernel, but the error message refers to modules for the 3.13 kernel.

Any idea what this could be and how to fix it?

Comment: That seems to be the 12.04 kernel. Did you copy any files over from the old server that might confuse modprobe or iptables?

Comment: this one is similar to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760505/issues-with-iptables).

Answer (score 3):

It seems I have solved it. 16.04 was installed over a disk containing an earlier version and for some reason it a) did not remove earlier kernels, and b) did not install the 16.04 4.4 kernel. 
solution -  I deleted all earlier kernels from /boot and all directories referring to modules for earlier kernels, and reinstalled. That got rid of the problem.

Comment: Removed all earlier kernels, still not working